# Derivatives over a Finite Element mesh

Tags: finite-element, computational-geometry, comsol

I have a data extracted from Comsol on some node points and I know the coordinates of each node.

Does anyone know how Comsol calculate the partial derivative from the values at each node and also using the coordinate information?

Comment: I can't talk about Comsol specifics, but in general, the derivatives are computed inside each element using the interpolation functions.

Comment: That's a question best asked on the Comsol forums.

Comment: I agree with Wolfgang, it is better to ask on Comsol forums. However, if you are unable to find out this information "the easy way" and really need it, you might want to ask a different question: "how to design a computational experiment to find out XXX". I advice against it before you try easier options.

Comment: how to design a computational experiment to find out how derivatives are computed in comsol! I'm curious about this too

Answer (score -1):

Derivatives in comsol are calculated according to the interpolation function. If the elements are linear, then the second derivatives of the unknown will be zero. If the elements are quadratic, then the third derivatives will be 0.

Comment: Not quite, it seems. I asked a related question a few days ago. You might find it useful. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42338/computing-higher-order-derivatives-with-linear-elements

Comment: thx, then my answer is the usual approach without derivative recovery